# Background video on ipad not fixed & href link on smartphone not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have two issues with coding a website for ipad and smartphone (in my case, iphone 5s).

1. In several browsers the code below works fine for a video background. *Did not check IE since I don't have a windows, but I'll worry about that later.*
   .
   But, when displaying the website on ipad, the video is somewhere in the center of the WHOLE website (so it ignores safari's viewport completely, to see the background you have to scroll down, then you see it behind the content that's [correctly] placed there). The video doesn't 'scroll down with the user' (so that it essentially stays in the same place within the viewport, not the whole height of the website).
2. When displaying the index page (with the 'continue to website' button) on a smartphone, the button / href link doesn't work. In other browsers it works (ipad / safari (laptop) / chrome / firefox). It doesn't do anything while tapping on the button.

Is there any way to fix these issues?

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<a href="main.html">
    <div id="verder">
        <p>verder naar de website</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
video { 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display:block;
    z-index: -100;

    background-color:#fff;
    background:url(../img/schrijven.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    /*background-position: 30% 50%;*/
}

div#verder{ 
    height:60px;
    width:321px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: white;
    margin: 0; padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    border:#ffffff solid 1px;
    border-radius:10px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}

div#verder:hover{
    background: rgba(168,225,210,0.3);
}

div#verder:active{
    /* koraal background: rgba(249,164,151,0.3); */
    background: rgba(156,149,145,0.3);
}

div#verder a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

div#verder p{
    font-family:'open_sanslight';
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Full website can be found at [www.divergencepr.nl](http://www.divergencepr.nl/)

**Edit 1**: Added two screenshots from my iPad, so that you can see what my issue exactly is. I don't think the video is playing either, but right now that can be because of my internet connection. I think that issue has to do with alignment, because when you go to other pages (that aren't as long), the background is visible, but there's a black bar above and below the image. But, when I change the `background-position` nothing changes on my ipad viewport.
[image: Landing page, no video or background visible]
[image: Scrolled down, there's the background!]

**Edit 2**: Tested the button on an android smartphone on chrome, button isn't working there either. Strange thing is that it DOES work on my ipad, while that is a 'mobile device' too?

Comment: Is this live somewhere? Or could you put a fiddle up?

Comment: @BrianBennett www.divergencepr.nl ;)

Comment: Have you tried setting your `html` and `body` tags to `height:100%` yet? You could also try `background-position:center center`.

Comment: @BrianBennett Just tried (example is now live) but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

i have with me ipad right now. I could help you with issue but i'm not understanding this

Added two screenshots from my iPad, so that you can see what my issue exactly is. I don't think the video is playing either, but right now that can be because of my internet connection. I think that issue has to do with alignment, because when you go to other pages (that aren't as long), the background is visible, but there's a black bar above and below the image. But, when I change the background-position nothing changes on my ipad viewport.

Can you do screenshot with pointer what are the issues?

Comment: If you see my start post, at the bottom there are 2 screenshots. In the black of the first screenshot, there should be a video. Or at least a still of the video. I only am able to test it on my ipad 2, don't know if it's different on other ipads?

Comment: @Lisa i'm testing on ipad 3 and video isn't coming up but when i go to direct link of http://www.divergencepr.nl/img/schrijven.mp4 it plays the video. in video tag try controls="true" and see it it helps.

Comment: wouldn't it be able to play automatically? Because the controls either be behind the content or in front of, which would mess up my design

Comment: @Lisa Please try this video download http://codemovement.pk/bayarea.mp4. i have encoded it to format of ipad. i hope it will work.